# What exactly is the difference between event driven architecture and message driven architecture in The Reactive Manifesto?

Tags: reactive-programming, typesafe, event-driven

I read the [Reactive Manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) .

But I could not understand the core differences between `event driven architectures` and `message driven architectures`. And as a result, I also could not understand the exact reason behind why the `reactive manifesto` prefers `Message Driven systems` instead of the `Event Driven` one.

I also had a look at this [interview](https://www.infoq.com/news/2014/10/thompson-reactive-manifesto-2), where `Martin Thompson` discusses the reactive manifesto.

But still, I could not clearly distinguish between these two architectures, their advantages and use cases.

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion, but you're wandering into the weeds. This sounds more like a pitch for a seminar series than anything I'd take seriously, and I'm saying that as a big fan of FRP in general (and indeed, I see nothing I conflate with reactive programming in the marketing-speak that I skimmed through in the link).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without sharing the view, I try to explain the claim:

An event implies a certain semantic, while a message is more about syntax. Thus a message *may* contain an event, but also something else (e.g., an error statement).

By focusing on the *mechanism* message, a better decoupling can be gained, since the semantic can be re-interpreted.

Comment: Can you please explain this part of your answer : `By focusing on the mechanism message, a better decoupling can be gained, since the semantic can be re-interpreted.`

Comment: @oblivion it means that the transport layer of your architecture shouldn't know about *what* its transporting. Its up to the receiver to "interpret the semantic".

Comment: @oblivion: Jared stressed the point (thanks!). To elaborate, an event is usually defined as a change in (a relevant part of) the state. A message in turn is a method to exchange information between loosely connected entities. A message *may* carry an event, but the receiver may have a different view on the state space (i.e. other semantics), or the receiver may even interpret this very message as simply "Uuups, something went wrong." or a command "act in this way".